# How can I dynamically resize a leaflet map after clicking a button?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, leaflet, ionic3

I have a leaflet map contained in `<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="false" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>`

This page is divided into `<ion-header>`, `<ion-content>` and `<ion-footer>`. The map is contained into `<ion-content>`. What I would like to do is hide the header and footer with a button.

So I created a button with `L.easyButton`. The code is the following:

```
L.easyButton('click',function(){
    if(self.hideLayout){
      self.map.addControl(setLayers);
      self.map.addControl(setZoom);
      self.map.addControl(toolBar);
      self.map.addControl(setScale);
      self.enableAdditionalButtons(textButton, arrowButton);
      self.hideLayout = false;
      self.hideFooter = false;
      self.map.invalidateSize(true);
    }else{
      self.map.removeControl(toolBar);
      self.map.removeControl(setLayers);
      self.map.removeControl(setZoom);
      self.map.removeControl(setScale);
      self.disableAdditionalButtons(textButton, arrowButton);
      self.hideLayout = true;
      self.hideFooter = true;
      self.map.invalidateSize(true);
    }
```

And I added the following code into the `<ion-footer>`:

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="!this.mapService.hideFooter">
```

What happens is that the map doesn't resize and remains a white band instead of the footer

[image]

I tried to use the invalidateSize leaflet method, even with the "setInterval" but without success. I think there is something about html and css to edit but I'm not an expert yet.

Again, really thanks to everyone in advance and I hope I was clear :)

Comment: what u can do is that when hiding the header and footer, u can set the map to get all device height.. like leaflet_element.style.height = (this.platform.height() - (stutus bar height in case of android or ios which u can get from google search)) + 'px' & leaflet_element.style.width = this.platform.width () + 'px'.. (width and height to be set together in case ur app works in portrait and lanscape modes)... and if user shows header and footer then set the leafter map to 100% height and 100% width...

Comment: @MostafaHarb Can you show me an example? I need to put this code inside the html or inside the code button? Anyway, at the moment, this app will be used only on computers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution that works for me. I'll post it here. I want to thank @Mostafa Harb for helping me.

```
L.easyButton('click', function() {
  const footerAndHeader = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-content') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>)[1];

  if (self.hideLayout) {
    self.map.addControl(setLayers);
    self.map.addControl(setZoom);
    self.map.addControl(toolBar);
    self.map.addControl(setScale);
    self.enableAdditionalButtons(textButton, arrowButton);
    self.hideLayout = false;
    self.hideFooter = false;
    self.hideHeader = false;
    self.map.invalidateSize(true);

    footerAndHeader.style.marginBottom = "40px";
    footerAndHeader.style.marginTop = "54px";
  } else {
    self.hideLayout = true;
    self.hideFooter = true;
    self.hideHeader = true;
    self.map.removeControl(toolBar);
    self.map.removeControl(setLayers);
    self.map.removeControl(setZoom);
    self.map.removeControl(setScale);
    self.disableAdditionalButtons(textButton, arrowButton);
    self.map.invalidateSize(true);

    footerAndHeader.style.marginBottom = "7px";
    footerAndHeader.style.marginTop = "3px";
  }
})
```

In my case the problem was the `<div>` with "scroll-content" class that were automatically created inside the `<ion-content>` tag. So, using `getElementsByClassName`, I took the second element in my array and I adjusted margin top and margin bottom for the header and for the footer.

Surely this solution will not be optimal and there will be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code I'll add my points;

```
constructor(private plt: Platform) {
    
}

L.easyButton('click', () => {
    const map = document.getElementById('map');
    if (self.hideLayout) {
      self.map.addControl(setLayers);
      self.map.addControl(setZoom);
      self.map.addControl(toolBar);
      self.map.addControl(setScale);
      self.enableAdditionalButtons(textButton, arrowButton);
      self.hideLayout = false;
      self.hideFooter = false;
      self.map.invalidateSize(true);
      map.style.height = '100%';
      map.style.width = '100%';
    } else {
      self.map.removeControl(toolBar);
      self.map.removeControl(setLayers);
      self.map.removeControl(setZoom);
      self.map.removeControl(setScale);
      self.disableAdditionalButtons(textButton, arrowButton);
      self.hideLayout = true;
      self.hideFooter = true;
      self.map.invalidateSize(true);
      map.style.height = (this.plt.height() - 26) + 'px';
      // 26 is the status bar, it may be 20 so u update it accordingly
      // source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/
      map.style.width = this.plt.width() + 'px';
    }
```

in case it didn't work, then you'll need to provide your ts code since (self) isn't much clear if it is like (this) or u just shared part of the function...

Answer (score 0):

`CSS`

```
.mymap{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    heightL 100%;
}
```

`HTML`

```
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="false" class="mymap">
    // your code
</div>
```

- add `display:flex` and set `height` and `width`

Comment: I already tried that, but in my case it didn't work